# Horizons SPK file with a different coordinate center than I asked for

Tags: observational-astronomy, horizon

I am using the [JPL horizons app](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/) to generate an SPK file for Chiron (ID: 20002060) with respect to the solar system barycenter (ID: 0). However, the generated SPK file says the center is with respect to the sun (ID: 10). What is happening and what is the correct center? I'm assuming the correct center is probably 10, but why is Horizons generating an ephemeris file with a different center than specified on the webapp?

## The Horizons Input

[image]

## The Generated Ephemeris

This is the text after decoding the binary data.

[image]

Comment: Note that the `Coordinate Center` button is ghosted, so you don't actually have a choice. Here's the SPICE Tutorials page: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/tutorials.html 18_spk may be helpful.

Comment: What do you want to do with this SPK file? Are you using it with the SPICE Toolkit?

Comment: @PM2Ring I was aware that the button is ghosted but I assumed the filled in value of SSB was the center of the SPK file. Maybe it's not and it's just a placeholder with no relation to the file. I ultimately found a workaround, but I am using it in a python script. I read the file in using the `spktype21` python library, and then integrate the kernel object with `skyfield`, but `skyfield` requires the data to be relative to the solar system's barycenter, so I just did some vector addition to make the correction